# What is the Jenkins Health Check Path in my TargetGroup supposed to be?

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I currently have a AppLB associated with a Target group that targets my EC2 running a Jenkins instance in a Docker Container, but lastly

I want to setup the Health check settings of my Target group that targets my EC2, but I have no idea what the health check path should be

So unfortunately I can't upload pictures, but this link will show what i'm reffering to
[Health check settings[1]:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQRLM.png

Thank you

Comment: You might try to check the `/login` endpoint (<SERVER_URL>\login , it is available for both authenticated and unauthenticated Jenkins instance and should always be available if the server is up and running.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, Health checker reports healthy

Answer (score 2):

I am using this for the health check at TargetGroup level:

```
TargetGroupJenkins:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup"
    DependsOn: VPC
    Properties:
      HealthCheckPath: /login
      Name: !Sub "tg-us-jenkins-${NameSuffix}"
      Port: 8080
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
          Value: 10
```